# Renewing certificates in web services using mutual (2-way) authentication

Tags: tls, authentication, java, mutual

I have a web service (let's call it Service X) which multiple other web services (clients) depend on. Communication between the Service X and any of the clients is done via mutual authentication (2-way SSL). The certificates (both client and server side certs) are going to expire in a few months, so we are preparing to replace the java keystores (again, client and server side) with new ones containing the new certificates.

Is there a better way to update these keystores besides having to bring down Service X and all of the clients, replace the keystore for each service and finally bring them all back up?